# Visual Studio 2013 IIS Website Name Property Missing

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013, web-deployment, continuous-deployment, web-deployment-project

Visual Studio 2010 Web Application Properties has a IIS Web site/application name to use on the destination server setting.  In my Visual Studio 2013 this setting is missing.

I need this setting for our continuous integration deployments when using .deploy.cmd with .SetParamaters.xml.  I have manually modified the .csproj file to include DeployIisAppPath in the below code for each configuration:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  <Optimize>false</Optimize>
  <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  <DeployIisAppPath>WebsiteName</DeployIisAppPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Where can I add this property in Visual Studio 2013 without manually modifying the .csproj file?

[image]